# Connecting two D-Link DGS-1210-48 switches for VLAN access

Tags: networking, switch, vlan

I am having trouble setting up 2 D-Link DGS-1210-48 switches so that a server connected to 1 switch can access the VLANs on both switches.

**Switch 1 config:

Ports 1 - 48 UNTAGGED in their own VLAN with PVIDs 1001 to 1048. Port 51 TAGGED in each VLAN

Port 49 and 51 - Untagged in VLAN with PVID 2

Port 49 - Patched to port 49 on switch 2

Port 51 - Linux server connected



Switch 2 config:

Ports 1 - 7 UNTAGGED in their own VLAN with PVIDS 1049 to 1055. Port 49 (The switch link) TAGGED in each VLAN

Port 49 - Patched port 49 on switch 1**

The idea is that each port on VLAN 1001 to 1055 there is a router connected (Every router is setup with a different ip range). The Linux server has a virtual interface setup for each VLAN so that it can access clients on every router.

The above configuration allows the server to connect to all VLANs on switch 1 where the server is physically connected (port 51), but it cannot access any of the VLANs on switch 2.

Could I please get some advice on whether or not what I am trying to do is possible, and if so, what have I done wrong.

NOTE: If I configure both switches so that port 51 (the server connection port) is patched to a dumb switch and I connect my server in to the same dumb switch, it can access ALL VLANs across both switches. I am trying to eliminate the extra switch hardware by "daisy chaining" the switches together directly.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Switch ports often perform ingress filtering, so the interconnection (trunk) ports must be members of both outbound *and* inbound VLANs. In other words, ports A[49] and B[49] must be members of the entire 1001..1055 range, not only their own ranges. Similarly, port 51 (server) needs to have VLANs 1049..1055 added.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I'm struggling to work out how this translates in to settings on the switches. Would I need to configure trunk ports on switch 1?

Comment: Well, technically yes, but if you currently have multiple VLANs added to the port, then it's *already* a trunk port – so just add the extra VLANs in the same way as you have already done. Actually, I've misread your description slightly, and the inter-switch trunk ports (i..e port 49) don't need all 1001..1055 VLANs, they only need VLANs 1049..1055, and only the Linux-server port needs the entire 1001..1055 range.

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for your previous answer and apologies for taking so long to reply. The switch doesn't give me any options to add VLANs to ports, just ports to VLANS (either tagged or untagged). I can't seem to find anywhere where the switch will allow me to allocate VLANs to ports.

Comment: It doesn't matter which way it's done in your switch's UI (some switches have a port-oriented list, others have it VLAN-oriented), the result is the same – if you add a port to two VLANs, that's the same as adding two VLANs to that port. So in switch 1, ports 49 and 51 need to be added to VLANs 1049..1055. (Though despite what I said in the post, you probably _don't_ need the entire 1001..1055 range on the trunk port, at least for now.)

Comment: Ah right ok thanks. I have tried a multitude of tagged and untagged combinations and it still won't work. There may be other settings required in the switch to make it work but I'll keep on trawling Google. Many thanks for your advice

Comment: Generally there aren't that many combinations; a port should have only one untagged VLAN – all others must be tagged (the tag is what allows a switch or router to distinguish between packets belonging to different VLANs). So even if VLANs 1049..1055 are untagged on normal  ports, they have to be tagged on the trunk port between switches (**on both ends**) and on the router port.